# How to validate a string value as a number in json text using JSON Schema?

Tags: c#, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I would like to be able to validate the answer field as a numeric value. The snippet below is one answer that is a part of a larger dictionary of answers. Each answer follows a generic format hence the need for the answer field to be of type string.

```
            "1": {
                "answer": "80035",
                "web_validated": true,
                "web_error_string": "",
                "server_error_string": ""
            },
```

This creates a problem as we are using JSON Schema to validate the dictionary of answers. We need the answer field to be validated as a numeric value, this is determined by a JSON template the dictionary must adhere to. Below is a snippet of the template for the above answer for one question in the dictionary.

```
      {
        "id": "1",
        "text": "KFI Number (Null required check)",
        "type": "text",
        "source": "phoebus",
        "kfid_mapping": "KFID000",
        "kfid_mapping_value": "",
        "valid_answers": null,
        "display_online": "readonly",
        "required": "1",
        "display_internal": "yes",
        "hints": null,
        "logic": null,
        "rules": null,
        "reason": null,
        "conditional_explanation": null,
        "conditional_question_id": null,
        "conditional_question_answered": null,
        "enabled": "1",
        "order": "2",
        "fk_section_id": "1",
        "validated": false
      }
```

Current JSON Schema we using to validate question id: 1.

```
"definitions": {
    "question1-1": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "answer": {
          "type": "string",
          "minLength": 1
        }
      }
      //other definitions removed
  } 
}
```

Above is the JSON schema definition for the answer shown in this question.

**Possible Solutions:**

1. Convert the answer field to a numeric field, i.e strip the "" - this
   does indeed work but its more expensive and is a hack. So pre
   process before validate it.
2. Just validate the answer field as a
   string, i.y  not null, not empty and min length checks.

I would prefer to see if this possible with JSON Schema?

Comment: Well, there's always [`pattern`](https://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#rfc.section.6.3.3) to specify a regex that then matches "number" (possibly as simple as `[0-9]+`, but you could get more fancy if you wanted to). Personally, I prefer to defer "semantic" validation like this to the processing layers, simply because it gives more flexibility. Generic validators rarely give informative error messages in this case, and short-circuiting regular processing can rob you of a chance to log extra details (and change your mind on exactly what's valid).

Comment: Yes, the above comment is right, the only way to do this would be to use regex as described. Feel free to join the JSON Schema slack via the discussion link on the website should you have any further questions =]

Answer (score 10):

As others mentioned you can use a pattern.  Here's the syntax added to your example:

```
"definitions": {
    "question1-1": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "answer": {
          "type": "string",
          "pattern": "^\d+$",
          "description": "Use regex to validate this string as a series of one or more digits"
        }
      }
      //other definitions removed
  } 
}
```